# what is the proper way to close streams on java's exec?

Tags: java, exec, try-with-resources

After

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

i see syscalls happening that show 2~3 file descriptors (FIFO pipes). What is the proper way to close them with try-with-resource pattern?

Most historical tribal knowledge found on java forums suggest:

```
# out of date!
... } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(p.getOutputStream());
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(p.getInputStream());
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(p.getErrorStream());
}
```

but that doesn't sound right because 1) method `closeQuietly` is deprecated and most libraries suggest using try-with-resource, 2) it is inelegant as I might not necessarily have all streams.
And simply moving the exec() call into try feels wrong as it is not the resource i will call close() on.

Comment: If you’re not doing anything with those streams other than printing them, you could just use [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead of Runtime.exec, and call the ProcessBuilder’s [inheritIO()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO()) method.  Then there is no need to manage those streams at all.

Answer (score 2):

Closing them isn't necessary; the close by themselves when the process dies. If the process never dies, it is also not neccessary: Either you make a new never-dying process every so often in which case your system is going to crash and run out of resources whether you close these or not, or you make it only once, in which case these resources aren't going to count for much. For what it is worth, these are quite lightweight resources, *and* often they simply cannot be 'closed' in the sense that the resources can be 'freed' - closing them either keeps them open but denies further chat (and sends EOFs where needed), or reroutes them to /dev/null; generally processes just have 3 pipes on em and will continue to have them until the process dies.

Yes, closeQuietly is a silly idea for virtually all purposes, and so it is here. If closing these streams somehow fail you probably don't want to silently ignore that.

If you must close them, the individual streams from these 3 are closable. However, note that you're reading rules of thumb and attempting to apply them as if they are gospel truth. try-with-resources is not always the right answer, and try-with-resources is not a 100% always replacement for close, let alone closeQuietly.

For example, try-with-resources specifically is designed around a period of usage. You declare the span of statements within which the resource should be available (the braces that go with the `try` block), and the construct will then ensure that the resource is closed only once code flow transitions out of that span of statements, no matter how it exits this. **That makes it probably irrelevant here, too!**

1. You are starting a long-lived process and don't care about the in/out. You just want the process to run and to keep running. This means there is no span at all, and you should just call `close()` on these if somehow you feel it is important to try to save the resources even though most likely this accomplishes nothing at all. No span-of-statements means try-with-resources isn't right.
2. You are starting a short-lived process that you interact with. The right thing to 'close' is the process itself, except you can't use try-with-resources for that. That can only be used on auto-closables. (resources where the class that represents them implement AutoClosable. Most do, some don't. Lock is a famous one. Process is another: To 'close' it, you invoke `destroy()` or even `destroyForcibly()`. You **cannot** use try-with-resources (not without ugly hacks that defeats the purpose) to do this! Once you close/destroy the process, the streams that went along with them are dead too.
3. More generally the principle is: If you create it, you close it. If you never call `getOutputStream()` you never created them. On some OSes, fetching these streams and then closing them wastes more resources than not doing this. Thus, if the argument is based on some sort of purity model, then you shouldn't close them either. If it's based on pragmatics, you'd have to test how heavy these resources really are (most likely, extremely light), whether closing them actually saves you some pipes (most likely, it will not), and whether `close()`-ing the result of invoking `getOutputStream()` on the process even helps *if* the answers to the above questions make that relevant (it probably will, but the spec does not guarantee this).

Answer (score 0):

They are very light processes that in almost every case don't require closing...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).